# how can I filter my packets in wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have to record results related to the packets I am sending to a destination website using wireshark. I don't know the IP address of the destination website. Since I am using Wifi there are many other network processes going on in the background. So how do I filter which are the packets sent to the website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform lookup for website IP address: open shell (applicable to Windows/Linux/MacOS) and type "nslookup site.name.com"
2. Filter by address